# How to find a general form solution of a Fredholm integral equation of the first kind when the integration support is infinite?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions

I am trying to find a general form solution of the following integral equations 
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty q F(q) J_1 (qr) \, \mathrm{d} q = 0 \, , & \text{ for } r \ge R \, , \\[6pt]
\int_0^\infty q (1-i\alpha q)  F(q) J_1 (qr) \, \mathrm{d} q = -\frac{ir(4h^2-r^2)}{(h^2+r^2)^{7/2}} \, , & \text{ for } r \le R \, , 
\end{align}
wherein $J_1$ is the Bessel functions of the first kind of order 1, $i$ being the imaginary unit and $\alpha$ and $h$ are known lengths.
The goal is the determination of the unknown complex valued function $F(q)$.

I was wondering if there exists a commonly used technique for the resolution of such homogenous integral equations.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

R